# How to export a pandas dataframe to a specific file path and append a date stamp to the end of the file path?

Tags: append

I have a data frame that I want to export to excel xlsx with a date/time stamp to the end of the file name.
I have the date time:

from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I:%M_%p")

datestr = date + 'xlsx'

df.to_excel(r"C:\somewhere\df + datestr")

any help would be great thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This one should work (python 3.6+):

```
file_path = 'C:\\somewhere\\df'
date = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I:%M_%p")
df.to_excel(f'{file_path}{date}.xlsx')
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your reply but it the only file I managed to get the code to export was 0kb with no xlsx extension:

Comment: data = pd.read_excel(r'F:\4. Fynn\Python Notebooks\vgsales.xlsx')



from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I:%M_%p")

file_path = 'F:\\4. Fynn\\Python Notebooks\\vgsales'


xlsx = '.xlsx'

Comment: For some reason when I use single backslash python doesn't output the code correctly - it replace some characters with 'x0'

Comment: apologies i am new to SO, my formatting is very poor :)

Comment: Yeah, I missed that '\' is an escape character in Windows,
can you try `'C:\\somewhere\\df'`?